# Where to find tensorflow pretrained models (list or download link)

Tags: tensorflow, pre-trained-model

I am starting to work with Intel movidius neural compute stick.
To start working, in my case, it is necessary to download pretrained models.
In the tutorials they refer to http://download.tensorflow.org/models/.

However, there is not a list that shows all the models available for download.

If the latest version of a net, lets say inception_v4, is not known, I cannot download the corresponding .tar.gz file.

Does anyone know a method to have an updated list of the .tar.gz files of the pretrained models available for download?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at [TensorFlow Hub](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following two links may help

1. [detection_model_zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md)
2. [TensorFlow-Slim image classification model library](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim#Pretrained)

Answer (score 1):

[keras.applications](https://keras.io/applications/) makes it easy to load models and their pretrained weights if you can use Keras

Answer (score 0):

Considering that most of the posted linked outdated, I suggest looking into the TensorFlow hub (https://www.tensorflow.org/hub) for more recent pre-trained models.