# How can I use the model.ckpt Files from Tensorflow Training on Google Cloud for making predictions?

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am using Tensorflow 1.15 and Python 3.7 and I am a beginner.
I trained a tensorflow model with my own dataset on google cloud as described here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf1_training_and_evaluation.md

After training my google cloud bucket had listed the model.ckpt files. I saved the model as described here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/exporting_models.md . Doing this generated some files: checkpoint, frozen_inference_graph.pb, model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001, model.ckpt.index, model.ckpt.meta, pipeline.config and a folder "saved_model" which contains a file saved_model.pb and an empty variables folder. So far so good. Now I wanted to use these files to make predictions using this notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/colab_tutorials/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb but I stuck at the "load object detection model" section, I always get this

```
OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: home/user/models/research/exported_graphs/saved_model/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried all the possibilities and read dozens of stackoverflow articles but I can't find any usable solution. Is there any other possibility to use the model.ckpt files which were generated by training to make a .h5 / make predictions?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Hi jojeko1994, welcome to the StackOverflow community. At first sight I think you are doing things correctly. Therefore, as the behaviour you get is not the expected one and your error will be difficult to reproduce in this moment, we would need more information to find out what is happening. This is the full Google Cloud guide on [exporting a SavedModel for prediction using AI Platform](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/exporting-savedmodel-for-prediction). Please take a careful look to see if there is something you are not doing correctly.

Comment: Could you also add to the problem description the complete folders/files structure of your SavedModel in your bucket? We should compare it to the one in [structure of a SavedModel directory](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#the_savedmodel_format_on_disk) to see if there are any differences. Could you also please share the whole log traceback of the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly upload `saved_model` on Google_cloud, and use below code snippet to load `saved_model`.

```
def load_model(model_name):
  #path to model directory
  model_dir = "model_directory"

  model_dir = pathlib.Path(model_dir)/"saved_model"

  model = tf.saved_model.load(str(model_dir))

  return model
```